# Unit Testing Local Functions (letfn) in Clojure?

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, scope, tdd

I spent a couple of years doing Scheme "back in the day" and am now learning Clojure. One of the "best practices" in Scheme was to define helper functions within the parent function thus limiting their visibility from "outside." Of course back then TDD wasn't done (or known!) so testing such functions wasn't an issue.

I'm still tempted to structure Clojure functions this way; i.e., using letfn to bind helper functions within the main function. Of course testing such "local" functions is problematic. I realize I can define "private" functions, but this scopes the visibility to the namespace which helps, but is not as fine grained. If you come upon a letfn within another function it's pretty clear that the function is not available for general use.

So, my question is, can one test such local functions and if so, how? If not, then is there some convention to aid in code reading so that it's clear that a function has only one caller?

TIA,
 Bill

Comment: Why unit test the internal logic of a function? If it is so complex that the parts should be tested separately, there is benefit to putting the definitions in their own top level forms.

Comment: Hmm. In addition to visibility, there's the issue that a letfn could close on a symbol, “intertwining” it.

Comment: Does Common Lisp's condition system give us a handle on this problem? If so, is there any Clojure equivalent?

Comment: I think you need to change your mindset more to write good Clojure code (and also Scheme). Make your helper function more functional (as in functional programming) so that they're safe to be public outside.

Comment: I don't see why local functions are "less functional" than top level functions (or any less safe.) The only difference is visibility -- it'd be the same function. I still maintain that using local functions makes their intended use more obvious to a code reader, but difficult to test.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to just put the functions in the namespace.

One option is using metadata:

```
user=> (defn ^{::square #(* % %)} cube [x]
  #_=>   (* x ((::square (meta #'cube)) x)))
#'user/cube
user=> (meta #'cube)
{…, :user/square #<user$fn__780 user$fn__780@2e62c3f9>}
user=> (cube 3)
27
```

It is of course possible to write a macro to make this prettier.

Comment: I have never seen this metadata approach before, and it makes me want to throw up. I don't see any advantage to this at all; it's just a gross way to do a :private function. If you want something more private than :private, use a letfn; metadata is not a reasonable compromise.

Comment: @amalloy OP doesn't want it as private as `letfn`. OP wants to be able to access the function from any scope.

Comment: So make the function public, with a note on it that says "don't use this unless you have a good reason". Or make it private and break into it via the var.

Comment: Hey, it may not be pretty, but it does appear to be a valid solution.  Plus, as noted, the ugliness can (fairly easily) be placed behind a macro.